# Can someone explain what Ok means in play framework?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I found the documentation [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2/api/play/mvc/results/Ok.html) but I do not understand what this class does. (I'm also new to scala coming from a java background so any explanation helps). Also what does "200 Ok" response mean as shown [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaActions)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A server receives an HTTP request message, interprets it and responds with an HTTP response message.

That is what the `Action` with Play does, it receives a request message and responds with a response message.

The first line of a response message is the status line.  This could be `OK`, `BadRequest`, `NotFound` and many more.  Full status codes can be seen [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

So, how we do it with Play is as follows:

```
def a() = Action { request => // this `request` is optional
  Ok("Here's your content")
  // BadRequest("You're asking wrong")
  // NotFound("You're asking for something we don't have")
  // etc
}
```

`Action` provides the `request` to our code block, with which we can interpret the request, and produce the response.  The `Ok` line specifies that the response message has the status code of `OK`. Then the rest of the response in the parameters and more - e.g., additional response headers using `withHeaders`.  The Play `MVC` API generally follows this pattern.  For example, `Ok.sendFile(new File("myfile.txt"))` sends the `Ok` status code with the file as the content.

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense